# In terms of clause analysis, does this constitute a complex sentence?

Tags: grammar, clauses

My usual grammatical spidey-sense has let me down here.

The sentence "I can’t begin to fathom how their tiny bodies would cope with what they had to carry" FEELS complex to me. I feel that

i) "how their tiny bodies would cope" is a subordinate/dependent clause.

BUT

ii) it also feels like the object of the main clause "I can't begin to fathom".

So I'm currently labelling it like this: **Main clause** [I can’t begin to fathom] + **subordinate clause** [how their tiny bodies would cope] + **prepositional phrase** [with what they had to carry].

Is this correct as you understand it - I feel there's some grammatical info I've missed here for this confusion to occur!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the words of CGEL (§ 10.1 p. 719), a complex sentence is recognized by the fact that "one or more of its elements is realized as a subordinate clause".
Thus, the object "how their tiny bodies would cope with what they had to carry"  being a subordinate, this sentence is complex; that is all there is to it.

"with what they had to carry" is a subordinate clause of the subordinate/ superordinate clause "how their tiny bodies would cope with what they had to carry".

[image]

Comment: There are 7 verbs in all, so one main (matrix) clause + 6 subordinate clauses.

Comment: [I can’t [begin [to fathom [how their tiny bodies would [cope with [what they [had [to carry]]]]]]]]".

Comment: @BillJ I am not at all familiar with this new grammar; you can see in the diagram that "would discover" is _one_ verb, or rather one verb phrase; in traditional grammar and for the purpose of sentence analysis, you do not take into account verbs but only verb phrases. I can't figure out, anyway, how"to carry" could be a subordinate to "I can't"; that makes no sense to me.

Comment: It's not new. "Would discover" is not a syntactic unit, not a single verb, but two verbs. Each verb heads a verb phrase, and each verb phrase heads a clause. It's the only way that makes sense. Clauses have been analysed like this for years.

Comment: @BillJ How do you explain that only one clause corresponds to "would discover" then? Are you saying that CGEL is an insane grammar? Since how many years, roughly?

Comment: @BillJ This is not the point of view in this contemporary grammar: https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/complex_sentence.htm " We can never obtain peace in the outer world until we make peace with ourselves." — "can…obtain" is in the matrix clause, give rise to a single clause.

Comment: You quote the joke website Grammar Monster, which is for kiddies, not grammarians.

Comment: You're not a native English speaker, nor a grammarian, are you.

Comment: @BillJ I am neither, but I like grammar, whether English or French.

Comment: What makes sense is analyzing the sentence this way: [I can't begin [to fathom [how their tiny bodies [would cope [with what they had [to carry]]]]]]. Each subordinate clause is introduced with an adverb, a coordinating conjunction, or *to*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I see: not just one matrix clause (also called superordinate) but a different one  for each subordinate (as there is no coordination); but this square braces scheme says nothing else than the tree scheme in the picture. It is not really _the_ right way, but only an alternate way (the most concise possible, apparently).

Comment: Further, "with what they had to carry" is not a clause but a preposition phrase. And further still, "how their tiny bodies would cope with what they had to carry" is not an object, but a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question). The meaning is "I can’t begin to fathom the answer to the question 'How would their tiny bodies cope with what they had to carry?'"

Comment: @BillJ How? Simply by reading it out in a serious reference (that follows in the footsteps of Jespersen)! I do understand your notation now; however, I don't think I am misleading anyone and in fact there is a point that remains unclear in your own information: you have a brace after "can't" whereas, if you take a look at user FeliniusRex comment, you see that the brace is after "begin", a world of a difference.

Comment: @BillJ I agree with your claim that "with …" is a prepositional phrase. However, for the next remark I don't follow your reasoning: it seems to me that you are mixing constituency and function. Subordinate clause is the nature of the element, object its function. example: "He took{ the content of the bag} (object)./ He took {what was in the bag} (object)."

Comment: @LPH Subordinate interrogatives are always complements -- that is common knowledge. Thus, the interrogative clause "how their tiny bodies would cope with what they had to carry" is **complement** of "fathom". I said that in my earlier comment to the OP.  You obviously didn't read it!